# npm install modules throwing an ENOENT error within local project inside vagrant box

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant, package.json

For some reason *I am getting an **ENOENT error** on **most** (but not all) modules that I try to install **locally**.*

All NPM install functions work - without SUDO (which is important on this system) - if I am in the root/global folder (home/vagrant/).

```
$ nvm --version
0.35.3
$ npm -version
6.14.4
$ node -v
v13.12.0
$ which npm
/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/bin/npm
```

But I have a local node project in /var/www/html/node/

Most NPM packages throw an ENOENT error when I try to install them but some seem to work: I can't work out why!

The following Work (and update the local package.json):

```
npm install underscore
npm install debug
npm install chokidar
```

But the far more important modules below all throw a variation of the same error (with or without sudo):

`npm install express`
`npm install webpack`
`npm install http-server`
`npm install npm-check-updates`
(and many others)

I can still node app.js within this folder if my script doesn't call any of these but as soon as I 'require' a modules that can't be installed it falls over.

The error I get on `npm install [module]` (with or without sudo, -g or --save/--save-dev) is a version of the following:

```
npm WARN node@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN node@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /var/www/html/node/node_modules/send/node_modules/debug/node_modules/ms/package.json.3354100157
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/html/node/node_modules/send/node_modules/debug/node_modules/ms/package.json.3354100157'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2020-04-11T11_00_48_913Z-debug.log
```

I have tried: 
 - Destroying my vagrant box and reinstalling it
 - reinstalling npm, node and nvm (a few times - which apparently seems to work but there are lots of 'red' depreciated warnings)
 - NPM cache-clean, npm prune, npm cache-clean -force, npm clean-install
 - deleting package-lock.json (and package.json) before each npm install 
 - Amending the 'global' install location within the global npm install through the below - however, this gives me a `nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option` error that insists I reset the prefix back to default.

```
    # Set global npm package install to a location that doesn't require sudo
    cd ~ && mkdir .node_modules_global
    npm config set prefix=$HOME/.node_modules_global

    # Now secondarily install npm in the new global location
    npm install npm@latest -g

    # Add the global npm folder to the path directory
    export PATH="$HOME/.node_modules_global/bin:$PATH"
    source ~/.bashrc
```

The error for the other modules is identical to the one copied above other than different paths (to /var/www/html/node/node_modules/assert/node_modules/util/*, /var/www/html/node/node_modules/follow-redirects/node_modules/debug/* and /var/www/html/node/node_modules/ansi-align/node_modules/strip-ansi*).  My node_modules folder doesn't contain these subfolders but I can't work out why NPM install won't add them!

Comment: Ok - so I have noticed that  'npm install webpack'  is dependant upon a number of other packages/modules that I can install manually. I have just done: `npm install pumpify webpack-sources micromatch has-values is-data-descriptor is-descriptor` successfully. I am still failing with some of the dependencies  like `npm install define-property` `npm install watchpack`  ... It seems that some of the essential global dependencies that I don't even need to install in the root, for some reason are not installed/recognised by npm init -y or npm update when I'm in a local instance... Why might that be?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Sadly not. Planning to spend the whole day on it trying to crack it tomorrow though so if you have insight insight v grateful! My initial install node process was: `wget -qO- https://cdn.rawgit.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
source ~/.bashrc

nvm install node`

Comment: This error persisted no matter what I tried (across multiple fresh vms on 2 different physical machines), however, I have switched my package manager from NPM to Yarn (still without sudo) and it seems to be working.

Comment: Yeah, I found this https://medium.com/@dtinth/isolating-node-modules-in-vagrant-9e646067b36. that worked for me